# Windows 10 WebView InvokeScript Not Working

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone, windows-10, windows-10-universal

My Windows 10 universal app is using a webview that uses InvokeScript to call the JS function "eval" while injecting some other javascript into the function. However, when I test it out, nothing happens. Debugging shows that the script is being stored correctly and it is hitting the function, but the webview doesn't seem to update at all.

```
private void browser1_LoadCompleted_1(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            count++;
            browser1.InvokeScript("eval", test);
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {

        }

        address.Text = browser1.Source.ToString();
    }
}
```

This code worked perfectly on Windows Phone 8 and earlier. But now with the Windows 10 webview, it seems to have no effect. This is the code for storing my script in the test variable:

```
private async void ReadFile()
    {
        string fileContent;
        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///Script.js"));
        using (StreamReader sRead = new StreamReader(await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync()))
            fileContent = await sRead.ReadToEndAsync();
        test = new string[] { fileContent };
    }
```

I'm not sure why nothing happens. I've confirmed the test variable does indeed contain the script when InvokeScript is called. I've even tested the InvokeScript with different and simpler JS scripts that definitely worked in the Windows Phone 8 version of this app. Is there something I'm missing to get the webview to update when the JS function is invoked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the solution was quite simple. Apparently InvokeScript has been deprecated in Windows 10 UWP and only InvokeScriptAsync works now. So all I had to do is make my method an async method and then await the InvokeScriptAsync call.

Answer (score 1):

InvokeScript in Windows 10 only works with trusted source. I have tried and got the same result as you. The exact script worked before on Win 8 no longer work on UWP.

Comment: So does that mean InvokeScript pretty much does nothing on UWP then? Or is there a way around it to make it a trusted source?